# What happens when I initialize a pointer with an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I understand how an array would decay into a pointer to the first element under certain circumstance.

I know that `int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5}` creates an array and that we can create a pointer `int *ptr = array` that after the assignment, also points to the first element of the array.

The thing is, what would happen when I do:`int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5}`?

I tried `printf("%d",ptr)`,`printf("%d",ptr+1)` and `printf("%d",ptr+2)` and it returns `1`,`5` and `9` respectively.

I tried `printf("%d",*ptr)` and it returns a `segmentation fault`

So I see that `ptr` points to the array `{1,2,3,4,5}`, and again tried:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%d",(*p)[i]);
}
```

and it returns `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`

Then I googled and can't really find what I am looking for.

Comment: `int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};` it should not compile. A good compiler should warn you `error: excess elements in scalar initializer `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement

```
int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

is having [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). An undefined behavior includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

When compiling program having this statement - `int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5}`, the compiler must be giving a warning message -

```
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};
              ^
```

Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called **scalar types**.

From [C Standards#6.7.9p11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11):

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. ..

Giving more than one initializer to a scalar is undefined behavior.
From [C Standards#J.2 Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> The initializer for a scalar is neither a single expression nor a single expression enclosed in braces

Comment: @Michi: See the last statement of my answer.

Comment: I Noticed to late....phone :))

Answer (score 6):

Using [decent compilation flags](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0511dbc2749b9964) gives the answer right away:

```
main.cpp:1:13: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};
            ^
main.cpp:1:15: error: excess elements in scalar initializer [-Werror]
int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};
              ^
```

You are implicitly converting `1` to an `int *`, and throwing away the superfluous initializers.

Pointer arithmetic, done in multiples of `sizeof(int)` (here 4), is what produces `5` and `9`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes `ptr+1` basically does a pointer arithmetic and in your case `sizeof(int)` seems to be `4`. That's why the resuts are `1+4` and `1+2*4` respectively.

Pointer arithmetic is dictated by the object it points to which is `int` here. And pointer moves by `sizeof(int)` that's why.

Also notice another thing, you have used brace enclosed initializer which generated the warning for multiple parameters inside `{}`. And `ptr` is initialized by `1` in this case. The behavior upon doing this is not defined but in your case it seems to be taking the first value in the list.

`printf("%d",*ptr)` is trying to read the what is there in the address pointed by `ptr`. In your case this generated segmentation fault - that means you tried to read a memory that you don't have permission to or you don't have access to.

To push you toward right direction, you can do this:-

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int *ap = a;
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
   // work with ap[i].
int (*p)[5] = &a;
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
   // work with (*p)[i]
```

Comment: Thats the reason why one should use `sizeof( * ptr )` instead of `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Michi.: Yes. True.

Answer (score 3):

The definition

```
int *ptr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

is equivalent to

```
int *ptr = 1;
```

The rest of the initializers are invalid, and most definitely doesn't make it an array.

If you want to have a pointer to an array without actually defining one, you could use [*compound literals*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
int *ptr = (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```